# can not load some pages html or css

Tags: php, html, css

I'm doing a database project for university, but actually my question is related to html or css (I think).

Here's the thing: I have a navigation bar around the website but when I'm in some some pages I can't access others, for example when I'm in "change password" page and I put the mouse over "Log Out" it's impossible to click.

Thanks in advance, André

Here's the code:

```
<div id="linking">      
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="trips.php">Search for trips</a>
        </li>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {

            if (($_SESSION['user_email']) === "admin@email.com") {
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="new_tour.php">Create tour</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="new_service.php">Create service</a>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

            <li>
                <a href='profile.php'>Change settings</a>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a href='change_password.php'>Change password</a>
            </li>                       
            <li>
                <a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>
            </li>
            <label>Hello <?php print_r($_SESSION['user_name']) ?>!</label>

            <?php
        } 
        else {
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href='login.php'>Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="new_customer.php">Register</a>
            </li>
            <label>Hello visitor!</label>
            <?php
        }
        ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
/* common properties */
body{
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

hr{
    color: firebrick;
    background-color: firebrick;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.registering {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0%;
}

.loging {
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    top: 25%;
}

td{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* .loging class properties */
body .loging{  
    position:absolute;
    left:32%;
    top:25%;
}

.loging td{
    padding:  5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: firebrick;
}

.loging td input{
    width: 500px;
    height: 23px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

.loging td input[type="submit"]{
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0px;    
}

.loging td input[type="password"]{
    font-size: 24px;
}


/*. registering class properties */
.registering td{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: firebrick;
}

.registering td input{
    width: 500px;
    height: 23px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

.registering td input[type="submit"]{
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.registering td input[type="password"]{
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* .linking properties */

#linking label{
    color: firebrick;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:right;
    position: fixed;
    left: 90%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

a{
    color:firebrick;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* section properties */
section{
    padding:5px;
    position: absolute;
    width:30%;
}

section table{
    padding: 8px;    
}

section hr{
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
}

section td, th{
    width:32%;
    text-align: center; 
}



/* search for trips */
body .search{  
    position:absolute;
    left:32%;
    top:25%;
}

.search td{
    padding:  5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: firebrick;
}

.search td input{
    width: 500px;
    height: 23px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

.search td input[type="submit"]{
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0px;

}
```

Logout.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']);   
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.php");
echo "<script>alert('You have been logged out! Please come back anytime!')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: As per your question you should add your css too.

Comment: Do you mean that nothing happens when you click logout?

Comment: @Djave I edited the post, I thought I pasted it

Comment: Can't see anything in the CSS of problem. I don't think this is a stylistic issue

Comment: @Giorgio exactly, I just can't click

Comment: use chrome tool like web developer or devTools to help you

Comment: But, does link work in other pages? What is the discriminant between correct behaviour and incorrect? i.e. when a user is logged in?

Comment: @Giorgio I'm checking if a user is logged in using $_SESSION['user_name'] and yes, if I'm in index page for example it works

Comment: Uhm... it's strange that a link (an identical link) works in some pages and not in others. I think the issue can be related to something inside `logout.php` page. Could you please post its code too?

Comment: @Giorgio I just had it but I think it's a perfectly normal code. It was working before

Comment: It's very strange.. I don't see anything wrong in logout code... the navigation bar you've posted is exactly the same both in `index` and in `change_password`? If yes, try to comment out everything but the navigation bar in `change_password` and try clicking logout. Let me know.

Comment: Yes it is, but I'll do it. Be back in a while, tks

Comment: I have a doubt: have you started session before checking `isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])`?

Comment: "Giorgio It seems that is this piece of code on css:

.registering {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0%;
}

I think it's because the navigation bar reached the "left:30%" and they are overlapped (I think that is the word)

And yes of course I did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70635/discussion-between-giorgio-and-andre-santos).

Comment: What browser are you having trouble clicking the link in?

Comment: Already solved the problem. Big thanks to @Giorgio

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not added the link(logout.php) to every page..